# Active Directory Enable/Disable application

Tags: active-directory

Is it possible to prevent an application to be launched based on the current logged in windows user accounts using AD?

Is this a configuration only thing in AD or the application itself has be coded somehow to prevent from being launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Group Policy Object with a Software Restriction for the application.  There are then several ways you can apply that restriction to just a select group of users (based on their AD user account.

Comment: So its a configuration only thing. No need for the application to be coded in a way that it has to check through AD if the user has the right to launched the APP, etc ?

Comment: Yes, just GPO configuration.  If you want to ensure they can't run the application, no matter where it is on the system or network, make sure you set up a hash value restriction.